# Running Appium Parallel - Multiple Chromedrivers

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

I am currently attempting to run my test across multiple devices. However, when I create the seperate Remote Web Drivers for the different Appium servers, Appium runs a taskkill on chromedriver.exe meaning only the latest driver remains. Is there a capability setting to stop this from happening, or is my approach wrong?

I am currently using an Appium grid setup on a remote machine, that accepts a sequential run, but I want to scale this to parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a `--bootstrap-port` (-bp) as well as a `--chromedriver-port` for each Appium server. Source: http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#parallel-android-tests

Also, if your parallel tests include usage of Selendroid automation, yet another port number is needed:

`--selendroid-port` the selendroid port (if using selendroid)